# Request error in C# MySqlCommand, but working in phpMyAdmin

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to make an update on my MySql database, but I don't understand why it doesn't work when executing from MySqlCommand, I have the famous message "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version" (I already have hundreds of queries working correctly, so I guess something is with syntax?).

edit 2 : Here is the part "near " :

`'В-513',PRIORITY=1050,QUANTITY_INIT=28,QUANTITY_REMAINING=0,FICHIER='C:\\Actcut3' at line 1'`

Here is the update query :

```
UPDATE launching_order_details SET 
ID_LO=1935,
ID_CONTRACT=4228,
ID_PHASE=11765,
ID_ASS=235314,
LIST_REP_ORI='1005817//В-513//235314//В1007//11765//1//30',IS_SUBDETAIL=0,
REF_DETAIL='3201\\1\\В1007\\В-513\\',
NAME='В-513',
PRIORITY=1050,QUANTITY_INIT=28,QUANTITY_REMAINING=0,
FICHIER='C:\\Actcut3.10\\Data\\Parts\\3201\\1\\В1007\\В-513.ini' WHERE ID=27701
```

Of course I send it in a same line, I just splitted it here for better readability.

If I make a copy/paste of query, then execute it from phpMyadmin, all is working fine.

Edit : C# code :

DBConnect class :

```
public void Update(string query)
{
    
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        if (isMySQL)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[vsteel].", ""), connection);        
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, MSconnection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("0", 1));
            //command.Connection = this.MSconnection;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
}
public bool OpenConnection()
{
    if (isMySQL)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //When handling errors, you can your application's response based 
            //on the error number.
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");

                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            Global.is_restarted = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            MSconnection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //When handling errors, you can your application's response based 
            //on the error number.
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");

                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            Global.is_restarted = true;
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

RepereLO class :

```
private void update()
{
    this.listRepereOri = this.listRepereOri.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ThenBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
    DBConnect DataBase = new DBConnect();
    string query = "UPDATE [vsteel].launching_order_details SET " +
        "ID_LO=" + this.launchingOrder.ID + "," +
        "ID_CONTRACT=" + this.contract.ID + "," +
        "ID_PHASE=" + this.phase.ID + "," +
        "ID_ASS=" + this.assembly.ID + "," +
        "LIST_REP_ORI=\'" + convertListRepereOriToString() + "\'," +
        "IS_SUBDETAIL=" + Convert.ToInt32(this.isSubRepere) + "," +
        "REF_DETAIL=\'" + this.refDetail + "\'," +
        "NAME=\'" + this.name + "\'," +
        "PRIORITY=" + this.priority + "," +
        "QUANTITY_INIT=" + this.quantity + "," +
        "QUANTITY_REMAINING=" + this.remainingQuantity + "," +
        "FICHIER=\'" + Global.ReplaceSpecialCharacters(this.fileName) + "\' " +
        "WHERE ID=" + this.id;
    DataBase.Update(query);
}
```

EDIT 2 : Parametirezed query

my DBConnect class

```
public void UpdateNew(string query, MySqlParameter[] myParamArray)
{
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[vsteel].", ""), connection))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myParamArray.Count(); i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(myParamArray[i]);
            }
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

In object :

```
    private void update()
{
    this.listRepereOri = this.listRepereOri.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ThenBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
    string query = "UPDATE [vsteel].launching_order_details SET " +
        "ID_LO=@idLo," +
        "ID_CONTRACT=@idContract," +
        "ID_PHASE=@idPhase," +
        "ID_ASS=@idAss," +
        "LIST_REP_ORI=@listRepOri," +
        "IS_SUBDETAIL=@isSubdetail," +
        "REF_DETAIL=@refDetail," +
        "NAME=@name," +
        "PRIORITY=@priority," +
        "QUANTITY_INIT=@qtyInit," +
        "QUANTITY_REMAINING=@qtyRemaining," +
        "FICHIER=@fichier" +
        " WHERE ID=@id";
    MySqlParameter[] listParams = new MySqlParameter[]
    {
        new MySqlParameter("id", this.id),
        new MySqlParameter("idLo", this.launchingOrder.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("idContract", this.Contract.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("idPhase", this.Phase.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("idAss", this.Assembly.ID),
        new MySqlParameter("listRepOri",  this.convertListRepereOriToString()),
        new MySqlParameter("isSubdetail", this.isSubRepere),
        new MySqlParameter("refDetail", this.refDetail),
        new MySqlParameter("name", this.name),
        new MySqlParameter("priority", this.priority),
        new MySqlParameter("qtyInit", this.quantity),
        new MySqlParameter("qtyRemaining", this.remainingQuantity),
        new MySqlParameter("fichier", this.fileName),
    };
    DBConnect DataBase = new DBConnect();
    DataBase.UpdateNew(query, listParams);
}
```

Comment: Both MySQL and C# use backslash to start string escape sequences - did you embed this string in a verbatim string literal in C# so that they're passed through to MySQL correctly? Or double escape them?

Comment: Syntax error messages have a `near '...` section, which tells you where mysql encountered the syntax error. Can you please share this part of the error message with us?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever not sure I understand : When I use backslashes, I always make them in double. I use exactly the same syntax (double backslash) for insert method, and in many other updates, and didn't meet any problem until now.

Comment: @Shadow just added it at beginning of the post

Comment: Thanks for your comments, this helped me to find the error, I forgot to call the function `ReplaceSpecialCharacters` on 2 fields using backslashes. (I do it to avoid users to insert queries inside code. I guess I can close the question

Comment: @Siegfried.V constructing queries by concatenating strings leaves you wide open to SQL injection, conversion errors and .... syntax errors like this. What happens if onoe of those fields/properties contained `O'Reily` ? You'd end up with eg `NAME='O'Reily'`. Oops. What if it contained `'; Drop table Users; #` instead? Use parameterized queries instead

Comment: @Siegfried.V `I forgot to call the function ReplaceSpecialCharacters` that's no kind of fix, just trying to cover up the coding bug. There's absolutely nothing special about `',#-"` or anything like that in a text field. The problem is the bad query. Use parameterized queries instead. It's actually **easier** than string concatenation, much less trying to remove "special" characters and then having to find a way to recover any mangled data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in fact I know on that part I have a big issue... I read somewhere(already forgot where) that I could make such function to avoid `'` from queries replacing them with this function (in fact, I replace backslashes as `'` by `\'`. isn't it a good way to do that without parameterized query (I already had a look to them one year ago, but it looked too complicated to implement, and didn't attach importance as my software is  only working on local computers, no internet). just read your last message. Will try to read again about these parameterized queries, thanks

Comment: @Siegfried.V it's not working at all though. And you had to add a lot of extra, buggy code to just make it work, when you could have written it correctly once and for all, for *far* less code than you used to concatenate. ` it looked too complicated to implement` no it's not. It's actually easier than what you've written just in `update()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos are prepared statements and parameterized queries the same? I found something here `https://zetcode.com/csharp/mysql/`, is this about that you are talking?

Comment: @Pangiotis can I ask you to have a look to my edit please? I managed to use parameterized function.  If I understood, the `CloseConnection()` is no more necessary, as I am using `using`. Then I read on many pages that a `Prepare()` is necessary, but I don't see it in your examples, isn't it obligatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is using string concatenation to construct a query from external input. This leaves the code wide open to SQL injection, conversion errors (what date format? decimal separator?) and ... syntax errors like this. What if `Name` is `O'Reily` for example? Or a user entered `' DROP TABLE Students; #` ? No amount of escaping or replacing is going to fix the real bug - using string concatenation.

The correct way to do this is to [use parameterized queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm). This is actually *easier* than concatenating strings. If you use a library like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper), it's as easy as :

```
string sql=@"UPDATE [vsteel].launching_order_details 
SET
ID_LO=@idlo,
ID_CONTRACT=@contract,
ID_PHASE=@phase,
ID_ASS=@assembly,
LIST_REP_ORI=@ori,
IS_SUBDETAIL=@isSubDetail,
REF_DETAIL=@ref,
NAME=@name,
PRIORITY=@priority,
QUANTITY_INIT=@initial,
QUANTITY_REMAINING=@remaining,
FICHIER=@path,
WHERE ID=@id";

using(var connection=new MySqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Execute(sql, new {
             id,
             idLo=launchingOrder.ID , 
             contract=contract.ID, 
             ....,
             path=fileName});
}
```

*Without* Dapper, the code is a bit more complex but still easier and safer to write than string concatenation and trying to replace characters.

```
using(var connection=new MySqlConnection)
using (var cmd=new MySqlCommand(query,connection))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",this.id);
   ...
    
   connection.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

BTW the `DbConnect` class has other issues as well. Long-lived database connections are a *bug* that harms performance and scalability. The locks taken during a connection remain active until it closes, which results in increased blocking for all clients. This happens even in databases with multi-version concurrency like PostgreSQL.

Connections are meant to be opened as late as possible and closed immediately after use. That's why you see all samples and tutorials create connections in a `using` block. This ensures the connection is close immediately after use.

ADO.NET uses connection pooling to eliminate the cost of opening a new connection, by reseting existing connections. When `DbConnection.Close` is called, the connection is reset and placed in a connection pool.

**Tutorials**

- [Basics of ADO.NET](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/guide/tutorials/basics/ado-net/) is a short intro to ADO.NET that explains what the various classes do and how they're used.
- MySQL's [Tutorial: An Introduction to Connector/NET Programming](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html) shows how to use ADO.NET with MySQL.
- Microsoft's [documentation on ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview) is almost an entire book that goes in great depth, so you should probably use it only as a reference
- [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) is a micro-ORM library that makes it *very* easy to map object properties to parameters and results to objects. It can be used with any ADO.NET provider, including MySQL.

With Dapper, one can write code like this :

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```

And the library will map the `Age` and `Id` properties to `@Age` and `@Id`. It will also map the `Age` and `Id` columns in the results to `Dog.Age` and `Dog.Id`

Comment: Thanks for this explaination. In fact this is the reason why I didn't change the code before. If I understood good, the problem is DbConnect class itself, I may not use it if I want to use parameterized queries. To be honnest, I am a bit "afraid" of changing it, because as you can guess, I use it maybe thousand times or more. What could you advise to use instead of DbConnect? (I see you talk about ADO.NET, is it something similar, I may replace DbConnect with?).Excuse if question seems "obvious", but I am not programmer myself, so some terms are not always obvious to me.

Comment: @Siegfried.V `I use it maybe thousand times or more` and how many problems like this have you encountered? Incorrect dates because you had to store a localized string instead of an actual date? Slow performance because multiple clients were blocking each other?

Comment: @Siegfried.V *your code* is using ADO.NET as well. `DbConnect` is a custom class that uses ADO.NET's classes like DbConnection and DbCommand. All data providers derive from those classes. When you use `MySqlCommand` you're actually using a class derived from `DbCommand`

Comment: first,  I know this is not the good method, but I answer to your question : I never met the problem before, here is how I did : for all strings, I use that methods that avoids `'` and `\` issues (just created a new update, and forgot to add them in update statement. For dates I always use a formatting when I insert/update them. For decimals the same, as I want the same format whatever the region the software is installed. About performances I didn't think about it, as the software is a local one, and as maximum will have 10 users at same time.Anyway reading (again) about it

Comment: may I ask ask you if you know a good tutorial for that? I read about it, and it seems that my "DBConnect" class will almost disapear if I understod, no more general `Update` function that allows me to update any table, I will need to move the code in the class itself, right?

Comment: `I always use a formatting` which assumes that the server uses the same format. What if it doesn't? What does `4/7/2021` mean? You don't know. If you store strings instead of dates, you won't be able to order or search them without using the ISO8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD). And even then, you won't know if someone *forgot* to use that format, storing garbage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237114/discussion-between-siegfried-v-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: As for a tutorial, check [Basics of ADO.NET](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/guide/tutorials/basics/ado-net/). MySQL's [Tutorial: An Introduction to Connector/NET Programming](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html) shows how to use ADO.NET with MySQL. Microsoft's [documentation on ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview) is almost an entire book that goes in great depth, so you should probably use it only as a reference